# stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.sendgrid.net:587

Tags: laravel, sendgrid, laravel-5.8

I send Emails using Sendgrid Service. In my local environment, it's working perfectly. but Production Server Environment I got the following error.

> Swift_TransportException GET /rpc/insurances/sendregisemail/a9e13e20-2910-11ea-88e2-534f2fd3cc6a .
>   Connection could not be established with host smtp.sendgrid.net :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.sendgrid.net:587 (Connection refused)

Comment: Please can you give more information about your production environment i.e. what operating system are you using? Are you using something like cPanel or Plesk?

Comment: The mail server might have blacklisted your hosting provider.

Comment: Cent Os and cPanel @Rwd

Comment: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/issues/846. I would suggest either checking your cPanel settings, getting in touch with your hosting provider and/or potentially getting in touch with SendGrid.

Answer (score 3):

This solved my problem

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp or MAIL_MAILER=smtp for Laravel >= 7
MAIL_PORT=587

To

MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail or MAIL_MAILER=sendmail for Laravel >= 7
MAIL_PORT=587